# Getting time since file was last modified in OS X using C?

Tags: c, macos, unix, time, posix

I have the following code that is suppose to print time passed since file was last modified:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    struct stat fileInfo;
    char * dir = "/Users/jenna/Desktop/Random.rtf";
    stat(dir, &fileInfo);

    printf("Last modified time: %s\n", ctime(&fileInfo.st_mtime));

    time_t mytime;
    mytime = time(NULL);
    printf("Current time: %s\n", ctime(&mytime));

    double diff = difftime(ctime(&mytime), ctime(&fileInfo.st_mtime));
    printf("diff : %f\n", diff);

}
```

Unfortunately, this code gives the following output:

```
Last modified time: Wed Apr  6 00:15:30 2016

Current time: Wed Apr  6 00:17:29 2016

diff : 0.000000
```

When I change the format flag in the printf to `%d`, I get the following output:

```
Last modified time: Wed Apr  6 00:15:30 2016

Current time: Wed Apr  6 00:18:34 2016

diff : 1983419808
```

Neither output is correct since I am expecting the difference of just several minutes( expressed in seconds). What am I doing wrong here ? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get into the practise of enabling compiler warnings.  This code should be giving you some very helpful ones.  Specifically, you're passing `char*` values into `difftime`.

Since `ctime` always returns a pointer to the same static memory, the two calls to `ctime` return the same pointer.  Now you are implicitly casting these to `time_t` (compiler warning!!!), and you get a difference of zero.

In the second case, you pass a `double` into `printf` and tell it you passed an `int`, which is undefined behaviour.

What you *actually* want is to pass `time_t` values into `difftime` like this:

```
double diff = difftime( mytime, fileInfo.st_mtime );
printf( "diff : %f\n", diff );
```

And get into the habit of reading documentation for functions that you are unfamiliar with:

- [Reference for `difftime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/difftime)
- [Reference for `ctime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/ctime)